# Is there any way to create column filters based on background color of cells in the grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am new to extjs and need to create a filter in the grid which can filter columns based on the background-color of the cells. I have setup the background-color on the cell as I want, but cannot find anything to create the filter which can filter the column based on the background-color.

I tried List filter, but it only supports the values inside the cells and not the background-color of the `cells`.

this is code to create cells with background-color:

```
renderer : function(value, meta) {
    if(parseInt(value) > 0) {
        meta.style = "background-color:green;";
    } else {
        meta.style = "background-color:red;";
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add filter based on the cell background color.

You should filter by param. You can add new parameter in model like `color` and use `convert` function to set value as color based on other column value.

Look eg.

```
{
     name: 'color',
     convert: function (v, rec) {
         return rec.get('otherParam') > 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
     },
     depends: ['otherParam']
 }
```